# how to remove the default title of Categories widget

Tags: categories, widgets, title

hi i'm using the Categories widget show hierarchy. I leave the space for title because I don't need to show any title. but it then displays on the website as "Categories". how can I remove that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a filter you can use to do this. (Kruti has even found it, but instead of using it, he modified core files...)

```
$title = apply_filters('widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? __( 'Categories' ) : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base);
```

So what you really need to do, is to add this to your functions.php:

```
function my_repair_categories_empty_title($title, $instance, $base) {
    if ( $base == 'categories' ) {
        if ( trim($instance['title']) == '' )
            return '';
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter('widget_title', 'my_repair_categories_empty_title', 10, 3);
```

Comment: i added this code in functions.php and it works well. but i have a doubt.is this function affect any other widget's title in future??sorry if my doubt is unnecessary.

Comment: It will affect any categories widget. No other widgets should be affected.

Answer (score 0):

add_filter for widget_title does not allow more than one parameter when called so the above will throw PHP warnings.

This seems to work instead:

```
function my_repair_categories_empty_title() {
    if ( $base == 'categories' ) {
        if ( trim($instance['title']) == '' )
            return '';
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter('widget_title', 'my_repair_categories_empty_title');
```

(tried to add this as a Comment to Krzysiek Dróżdż but don't have enough rep to do so)